# Unit Testing failing with kotlin IllegalStateException

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm trying to verify that when I call my createUser interactor in my presenter, a user is created into Firebase.

To do this I simply implemented this test case

### RegisterTest.class

```
    @Captor
    var callbackCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<RegisterInteractor.RegisterCallBack>? = null

    @Mock
    lateinit var view: RegisterContract.View

    @Mock
    lateinit var interactor: RegisterInteractor
    lateinit var presenter: RegisterPresenter


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        presenter = RegisterPresenter(interactor)
        presenter.attachView(view)
    }

    @Test
        fun should_SignUpUser(){
            //give
            presenter.signUp("testUser","testEmail@gmail.com","123456")
            //when
            verify(interactor).createUserWithEmailAndPassword("testUser","testEmail@gmail.com","123456", callbackCaptor!!.capture())
            callbackCaptor?.value?.onRegistrationSucces()
            //then
            verify(view).navigateToMain()
        }
```

### RegisterInteractor Callback

```
interface RegisterInteractor {

    interface RegisterCallBack {
        fun onRegistrationSucces()
        fun onRegistrationFailure(errorMsg:String)
    }

    fun createUserWithEmailAndPassword(fullName:String,email:String,password:String,listener:RegisterCallBack)
}
```

### RegisterPresenter

Here is where I call the signUp method to test

```
 override fun signUp(fullName:String, email: String, password: String) {
        view?.showProgress()
        registerInteractor?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(fullName,email, password, object : RegisterInteractor.RegisterCallBack {

                override fun onRegistrationSucces() {
                    if(isViewAttached()){
                        view?.navigateToLogin()
                        view?.hideProgress()
                    }
                }

                override fun onRegistrationFailure(errorMsg:String) {
                    if(isViewAttached()){
                        view?.showError(errorMsg)
                        view?.hideProgress()
                    }
                }

            })
    }
```

### RegisterInteractorImpl

```
  override fun createUserWithEmailAndPassword(fullName:String,email:String,password:String,listener: RegisterInteractor.RegisterCallBack){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, set full name and navigate to main.
                    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                    val profileUpdates = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName(fullName)
                        .build()

                    // Checks if the user is already in the database, if not, it will write it and go to the main activity
                    user?.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                        ?.addOnCompleteListener { updateTask ->
                            if (updateTask.isSuccessful) {
                                userRepository.createUser(fullName,email,object : UserRepository.UserRepositoryCallback{

                                    override fun onRemoteSuccess() {
                                        listener.onRegistrationSucces()
                                    }

                                    override fun onRemoteFailure(errormsg:String) {
                                        // Since the task is the one who decides if an user is created or not by checking if the email is not duplicated, this callback has no effect on saving a call to Firestore
                                    }
                                })

                            }
                        }

                } else {
                    listener.onRegistrationFailure(task.exception?.message!!)
                }
            }
    }
```

And I'm getting a **IllegalStateException** when executing my test, this is the following message I receive

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: callbackCaptor!!.capture() must not
>   be null
>
> at
>   com.logintest.presentation.register.presenter.RegisterPresenterTest.should_SignUpUser(RegisterPresenterTest.kt:123)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

And the line it refers the error is on the test

```
verify(interactor).createUserWithEmailAndPassword("userTest","userEmail@gmail.com","123456", callbackCaptor!!.capture())
```

Where is this error coming from ?

Thanks

Comment: `callbackCaptor` is null

Comment: I have seen many articles where the ArgumentCaptor is initialized the way I do it, Im doing it wrong ?

Comment: Try making it `callbackCaptor?.capture()` or `callbackCaptor?.capture()!!`. The callback isn't returning properly I guess

Comment: it isnt working either